# How can I retrieve data in single string instead of list from database using HQL?

Tags: sql, hql

My query is

```
SELECT um.userName FROM USER_MASTER um
```

This query gives result in list (4 Row and 1 Column) like

John
Tommy
Nancy
Andy

But I want to result (1 Row and 1 Column) like

John,Tommy,Nancy,Andy

Comment: why don't concatenate the results received to form the string you want.

Comment: this is my child query. And Parent query is big. and i want to fetch result depends upon parents element. Is it possible?

Comment: Edit your question, and tell us what you *actually* want to achieve.

Comment: Refers this link (http://www.williamrobertson.net/documents/one-row.html)